# How to execute shell script command in other terminal window

Tags: bash, shell

i have a quick question. I just wonder how i can execute command in shell script. Code should checking if python script is running, if not i want to run it again but in another terminal window. Shell code below.

```
while :
do
    if pgrep -f "python instagram_bot.py" &>/dev/null; then
        echo "it is already running"
        sleep 1
    else
        python instagram_bot.py
    fi
done
```

I'm using macOS system

In else statement i just wondering it is possible to execute command that open new terminal and run python script.

Thanks for any help, Best, Kacper

Comment: You didn't say which OS you use. Nor which terminal.

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, I'm using macOS System. I got this link that should show an answer. Unfortunately i cannot find it there.

Comment: I am voting to re-open this question as the duplicate that has been identified specifies `gnome-terminal` and is not applicable to **macOS**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using **Terminal** on **macOS**, you can run:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' \
  -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using {command down}' \
  -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "python instagram_bot.py" in front window'
```

---

You can start **Terminal** by using a *"Spotlight search"* by typing <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> and typing *"Terminal"* and hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> as soon as it guesses "Terminal.app".

Then, at the top-left of the screen, click **Shell** -> **New Window** and you will see that the shortcut for a new window is <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>n</kbd>. That's why the `osascript` above does `keystroke "n" using {command down}'` - it starts a new window.

Comment: Thanks man, it's works. If i can ask, can you tell me how i can deal with this on Windows analogous to what you wrote in the solution for macos ?

Comment: Sorry, I know very little about Windows.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I have last question, how i can pass any variable to python script, I'm using something like this ``` \"$COUNTER\" \"$b\" \"$c\" ``` but when i run my python file and pass ``` print(sys.argv) ``` I'm getting empty list only with file name. Best, Kacper

Comment: Ugh! It's hard to read code in comments. Questions are free, so just ask a new one. Show the command you actually want to run, and show the code with your attempt.

Comment: Ok, i will pass link here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74335091/how-to-pass-variable-in-shell-script-and-read-it-in-python-script, Thanks