# How to pass variable in shell script and read it in python script

Tags: python, bash, macos, shell

I want to run my python script through the shell, passing variable `a`.

Here is my code:

```
else
    a=0
    osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' \
        -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using {command down}' \
        -e 'tell application "Terminal" to do script "python /Users/kacperXXX/instagram_bot.py \"$a\"" in front window'
    sleep 5
    exit
fi
```

My script just prints its arguments.
When I run it I got empty list only with file path.

**Output**

```
['/Users/kacperleczynski/Desktop/instagram_bot.py', '']
```

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass arguments as input using the `sys` module.

When using your script, you call:

```
python test.py var1
```

Inside test.py, in the first lines you must import `sys`:

```
import sys
print(sys.argv[0]) # prints test.py
print(sys.argv[1]) # prints var1
```

You can use `a` instead of `var1` as input.

Comment: Thank you, but how i can pass variable, I want to make counter variable and passing each time when new terminal window is open

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways of approaching this. The reason your script is not currently working is that variables aren't interpolated (substituted in) inside strings that have single quotes around them. Variables are only substituted in within strings surrounded in **double quotes**. So you need to have the string with your variable `a` in it surrounded by double quotes. But if you do that, the double quotes in there already will end your string, so you need to escape them with a backslash.

Here's one way - notice the last line is in **double** quotes:

```
#!/bin/bash

a=42

# Method 1
osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' \
        -e 'tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using {command down}' \
        -e "tell application \"Terminal\" to do script \"python3 /path/to/script.py $a\" in front window"
```

And here's another way using a `here-doc`, i.e. *"here's the stuff to execute"*:

```
# Method 2
osascript <<EOF
tell application "Terminal" to activate
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "n" using {command down}
tell application "Terminal" to do script "python3 /path/to/script.py $a" in front window
EOF
```

Comment: This's what i  wanted. Thank you man :). Best